# Output enum name as enum value in a dict showing class attributes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums

I have an enum and a dataclass as following.

```
class Mode(Enum):
    MODE_A = auto()
    MODE_B = auto()

@dataclass
class BaseDataClass:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    mode: Mode

    def to_dict(self):
        return vars(self)
```

the `to_dict` function displays

```
b = BaseDataClass(a=1, b=2, c=3, mode=Mode.MODE_A)
b.to_dict()

> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'mode': <Mode.MODE_A: 1>}
```

I'd like to output the mode name as its value like `'mode': 'MODE_A'`. I tried to use dunder methods like `__str__` and `__repr__` in the enum class but it didn't work. AS it is supposed not to edit `__dict__` values, Does anyone suggest a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Does it work as you want if you just do `print(Mode.MODE_A)`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, by print, it shows like this `>>> print(Mode.MODE_A)` then `Mode.BUDGET`

Comment: If you're worrying about how this prints in the command line interpreter, then you are worrying about nothing.  For your users, you will do formatting, and it will look correct.

Comment: What I want to have is a way to output a dict that has `{'mode': 'MODE_A'}` instead of {`'mode': <Mode.MODE_A: 1>}` by that by that `to_dict` function.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you tried for your `__repr__`, but this works:

```
class Mode(Enum):
    MODE_A = auto()
    MODE_B = auto()
    #
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

and in use:

```
>>> {'mode': Mode.MODE_A}
{'mode': MODE_A}
```